# SELECTING with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

This is my table [orders] in DB

```
ID   link        Status   quantity
-----------------------------------
118  aaaa       Pending     1
119  bbdbdb     In Progress 2 
120  asdasdas   Complete    3 
121  dasdasda   Processing  1  
122  aaaa       Cancel      2
```

I want to select in "Link" where status is pending or processing or in progress. is this correct way to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE link= '$link' AND status='Pending' OR status='In Progress' OR status='Processing'"
```

Comment: No it’s not, because AND binds stronger than OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use IN clause for the same

```
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE link= '".$link."' AND status IN ('Pending','In Progress','Processing')"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE link= '$link' 
  AND ( 
    status='Pending' 
    OR status='In Progress' 
    OR status='Processing' 
  )
```

Comment: this solution is too slow. Better is IN. Best solution is create table with status.

Comment: Don't assume slow & preoptimize. Also there might be more statuses than visible in the example.

For all I know status might be of ENUM type or in table index then it's all up to query optimizer to evaluate fast options.

Answer (score 0):

This was faster then IN three values.

```
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE link= '".$link."' AND status NOT IN ('Complete','Cancel')"
```

---

But best solving are create table with status and using FOREIGN KEY

```
CREATE TABLE status (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)
```

In table orders using these FOREIGN KEY status.ID